# How to stop Windows from generating random album art files

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I've had this problem for a while now. Windows or some other program on my computer automatically creates hidden files containing album art or song art in my music folders such as `"Folder.jpg"` or `"AlbumArtSmall.jpg"`. I'm looking for a way to make this random generating stop because it's messing up my music library in `Zune.` I use `MP3Tag` and iTunes to apply song art manually to my songs, but the picture files that appear in the folders replace the song art that I added myself and it messes everything up.
In attempt to fix the issue I disabled all of the automatic album art downloading in "`Tools > Options > Library`" in Windows Media Player (just in case it was causing the problem) but still nothing. I tried deleting these files but they just come back again after a while. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This question should be better moved to super user I guess.

Nevertheless, there are two steps:

1.Disable the setting "download additional info from the Internet" in your Windows Media Player (Tools -> Options).

2.Insert the picture INTO the music files by using the free tag editor e.g. [MP3TAG](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/)